# Can't align bootstrap containers next to each other

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want them to float left next to each other. I don't get why they won't. I've tried everything including trying to reduce the margin to 10px. What could be the problem? I need a row of 3 containers aligned floating from left.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="includes/sample.png" alt="...">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
        <p>...</p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Buy!</a> 
        </p> </div> </div> 




    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="includes/sample.png" alt="...">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
        <p>...</p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Buy!</a>
        </p> </div> </div>


    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="includes/sample.png" alt="...">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
        <p>...</p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Buy!</a>
        </p> </div> </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Here is my custom CSS

```
.thumbnail {
    float:left;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

and here is the result:

[image]

Comment: here is my HTML part

Answer (score 2):

Use the Bootstrap grid. Since you want 3 columns, use `col-sm-4` which spans 4 of the 12 columns across (12/4 = 3). Then you won't need the extra CSS to float the `.thumbnail`.

http://www.codeply.com/go/UoRlotGrut

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="includes/sample.png" alt="...">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                    <p>...</p>
                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Buy!</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="includes/sample.png" alt="...">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                    <p>...</p>
                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Buy!</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="includes/sample.png" alt="...">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                    <p>...</p>
                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Buy!</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but they aren't aligned horisontal then. They will just be aligned vertically.

Comment: OK, the question was how to put them next to each other, not horizontally align them. Also, `row` should be used inside a container, and your code didn't specify a `container` or `container-fluid` so maybe the smaller width `container` is closer to what you want. They are aligned horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

Just create another row within the parent column and then add 3 columns in that row(spanning 4 each)

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
           <div class="thumbnail">
              <img src="includes/sample.png" alt="...">
              <div class="caption">
                 <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                 <p>...</p>
                 <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Buy!</a> 
                 </p>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
           <div class="thumbnail">
              <img src="includes/sample.png" alt="...">
              <div class="caption">
                 <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                 <p>...</p>
                 <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Buy!</a>
                 </p>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
           <div class="thumbnail">
              <img src="includes/sample.png" alt="...">
              <div class="caption">
                 <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                 <p>...</p>
                 <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Buy!</a>
                 </p>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```